# nyc coveralls integration not working

Tags: travis-ci, istanbul, coveralls, ava

I try to make `nyc` working with `coveralls` following the instruction:
https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#integrating-with-coveralls

But I can't get it to work. Here is an example repo:
https://github.com/unional/showdown-highlightjs-extension

Travis build is successful: https://travis-ci.org/unional/showdown-highlightjs-extension

And Coveralls notice the build, but does not seem to get any data:
https://coveralls.io/github/unional/showdown-highlightjs-extension

Here is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: node_js

notifications:
  email:
    on_success: never
    on_failure: change

node_js:
  - "stable"

before_install:
  - npm install -g npm

script:
  - npm run verify

after_script:
  - npm install coveralls && npm run coveralls
```

And here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "coverage": "npm test && nyc check-coverage --branches 85 --functions 85 --lines 85",
    "coveralls": "nyc report --reporter=text-lcov | coveralls",
    "test": "npm run clean && tsc && nyc ava"
    ...
  },
  "nyc": {
    "exclude": [
      "scripts",
      "**/*.spec.*",
      "**/fixtures/**/*"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue is in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceRoot": "/showdown-highlight-extension"
    ...
  }
}
```

This setting gives me the correct (I assume) source map in the browser. See [What's the proper way to set sourceRoot in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585885/whats-the-proper-way-to-set-sourceroot-in-typescript)

[image]

But is not liked by the coverage tool.

Once I remove it, it starts working.

Need to find an answer to that question.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding your Coveralls repo API token (which can be found on the Coveralls page for your repo) to a new `COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN` [encrypted environment variable](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/) on Travis, as per the (somewhat sketchy) documentation [on the Coveralls site](https://coveralls.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201347419-Coveralls-currently-supports).

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding the `COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN`, but it still say "no data" in the coveralls site.

Comment: travis:  https://travis-ci.org/unional/global-store     coveralls:  https://coveralls.io/github/unional/global-store

Comment: Hmm. Try merging the two `coverage` and `coveralls` npm script commands together, so your `nyc report ...` command gets run straight after the `test` and `check-coverage` commands. Maybe one of your other `npm` script commands is deleting the test coverage files that `nyc` is creating.

Comment: Also make sure that your Typescript transpilation is generating source maps, as `ava` tests [use those for coverage checking](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ava#code-coverage).

Comment: I tried a few things and it still not working. I print out the result from `nyc report ...` to show that it does have the data when it is being piped to `coveralls`. You can see it here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/190190241/log.txt (scroll to the end)

Comment: Maybe try deleting the Coveralls pages for your repos, and re-creating them?

Comment: They are new repos added to coveralls. I will give it a try anyway. :)

Comment: Sorry, I have no more ideas. I even tried forking and running my own tests, I didn't get any Coveralls data either, then I tried CodeCov and that didn't get any either ( https://travis-ci.org/ocean/global-store ). I don't know much about Typescript, maybe something in there is not configured right?

Comment: Thanks for you help. I know it is working, e.g. https://github.com/typings/core  So need to figure out what's the difference. (one different is using different test framework).